# dplyr in Rcpp: Do a left join in Rcpp using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rcpp

I am trying to use `dplyr` in Rcpp to do the following:

```
> df1 = data.frame(vec1 = c(2,2,3,3,4,5,5,5))
> df2 = data.frame(vec1 = c(2,2,2,2,4,5,6,6), vec2 = c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test1", "test2", "test2", "test1", "test4"))
> df3 <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "vec1")
> df3
   vec1  vec2
1     2 test1
2     2 test2
3     2 test3
4     2 test1
5     2 test1
6     2 test2
7     2 test3
8     2 test1
9     3  <NA>
10    3  <NA>
11    4 test2
12    5 test2
13    5 test2
14    5 test2
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to call the `left_join` function in Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <dplyr.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(dplyr,BH)]]

void test_join(Rcpp::DataFrame df1, Rcpp::DataFrame df2){

  Rcpp::DataFrame df3 = ; // This is what I am missing 

}
```

I was reading through the `src` files of dplyr on github, and I saw the function `left_join_impl` in this [file](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/e3da92008ca0c8b4c84373bf2b7947c8eb5e9ee8/src/dplyr.cpp). Is this the function to be used? If so, I'm not sure how to use it correctly because there is no documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitively not the most elegant and fastest way to do this, but it serves as a simple workaround:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code='
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame test_join(DataFrame df1, DataFrame df2, Function left_join) {
return(left_join(df1, df2, "vec1"));
}')

test_join(df1, df2, dplyr::left_join)
```

And it has one advantage over importing `dplyr.h` to your C++ code: You do not have to rely on the internal functions of dplyr which may change in future versions. Probably the API functions like `left_join` will be downwards compatible, hence this code will highly probably work with future versions of dplyr.

But as this causes many wrappings and unwrappings it can be a serious performance issue if `test_join` is called many times.

Comment: Note that this approach does _not_ implement a native C++ accessor to `dplyr`. Instead, the author is calling an **R** function *from* **C++** using `Rcpp::Function` hook.